# Variables with conditionals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a conditional statement which determines the color of my highcharts lines. I have multiple charts in which I'd like to repeat this conditional. Currently I'm finding that I have to repeat the code in each chart as I can't seem to do a variable with the conditionals stored. This goes against any DRY method, and will seem troublesome in the future.

**My chart** (using Lazy highcharts gem)

```
@chart_1 = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  @sales.sale_selections.flat_map { |ss|
   f.series(animation: false, type: 'spline', name: ss.sale_type.name,
   data: ts.sale_methods.map { |sm| { y: sm.sales_total.to_f, x: sm.days }}, color: 
   if ss.sale_type.name.include? 'soda'
     'red'
   elsif ss.sale_type.name.include? 'chips'
     'blue'
   else
     'black'
   end
  )}
end
```

Is it possible to have the conditional as a variable in which to call upon when needed. For example (which doesn't work, but using as a example):

```
@colours = if ss.sale_type.name.include? 'soda'
             'red'
           elsif ss.sale_type.name.include? 'chips'
             'blue'
           else
             'black'
           end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Write a function to return the color you want.

```
def row_color(sale_type_name)
  if sale_type_name.include? 'soda'
    'red'
  elsif sale_type_name.include? 'chips'
    'blue'
  else
    'black'
  end
end
```

Then call the function to get the color

```
@colour = row_color(ss.sale_type.name)
```

Comment: Thanks John, getting the same error as previously getting. undefined local variable or method `ss'.

Comment: Putting row_color(ss.sale_type.name) direct into the chart worked.